# Calculating distance (lat, lon) for geom point using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geometry, distance, latitude-longitude, proximity

I have `point` in my db (Postgres postgis):

```
CREATE TABLE geometries (name varchar, geom geometry);
```

With example data:

```
INSERT INTO geometries VALUES ('Point', 'POINT(0 0)');

INSERT INTO geometries VALUES ('Point', 'POINT(10 0)');
```

I would like to select one point closest to input - for example (1, 1)

It must be geographics distance using `haversine formula` (https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

What is the best way (fastest by performance) how can I do it?

Comment: Use a geography column rather than a geometry column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [nearest neighbour](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/knn.html) operator

```
SELECT * FROM geometries
ORDER BY geom <-> ST_GeogFromText('POINT(1, 1)')
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: note that the [`<->` operator](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html) measures distances based **on a sphere** for `GEOGRAPHY`; if '*using haversine*' (i.e. **spheroidal** geometric algebra) is mandatory, one will need to `ORDER BY ST_Distance(<geography_a>, <geography_b>)`

Comment: @ThingumaBob I was under the impression that ordering by `ST_DISTANCE` was horribly slow and inefficient. Wouldn't it be enough to cast geometry to geography? Ie, `ORDER BY geom::geography <-> ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1, 1)')::geography ` ?

Comment: @hunter it's as efficient as ordering in general. the advantage of the `<->` operator is the implicit check of the index to consider only geometries in the actual neighborhood; adding sth. like `WHERE geom && ST_Expand('POINT(1 1)'::GEOMETRY, <threshold_in_degree_eg_0.001>)` would help to limit actual calculations to nearby points (but obviously doesn't guarantee to find a neighbor). casting to `GEOGRAPHY` is definitely what you want, but the `<->` operator is hardcoded to 'only' measure on a sphere, wheras `ST_Distance` uses a spheroid for `GEOGRAPHY` by default.

Comment: @hunter your answer is still +1! ...actually, there is almost *no need at all* to use `GEOGRAPHY` precision for nearest neighbor searches; for 99.5% of cases, topology is completely independent from the impact of longitudinal measurement discrepancy or great circle distance differences when using 2D LatLon 'projections'!